# "OSError: The handle is invalid" when running Chrome with undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver

```
Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x000001E13DE9C900>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MD. MINHAZ\PycharmProjects\tender_scraper_eu\.venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 843, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\MD. MINHAZ\PycharmProjects\tender_scraper_eu\.venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 798, in quit
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I did not expect any exception here.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular, question title should concisely summarize the issue so other users can decide if they should click into your question.

Comment: Also, please always include the relevant code in addition to the error message.